# Delimit Excel in different formats in one action

Tags: excel, excel-formula, delimiter, separator

I would like to ask if this is possible. In 1 cell there is a data for names. e.g. "Dela Cruz, Juan" and "Juan Dela Cruz". I would like to separate them in cell that has a tag of first name in full name.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you would like to achieve:
[image: different delimiters]

Formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))>0,
     TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(",",A2))),
     TRIM(LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)))
```

Formula in `C2`:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))>0,
     TRIM(LEFT(A2,(FIND(",",A2)-1))),
     TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2))))
```